# How to get alias working on server that is connected via ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, alias, xterm

I connect to another server using command:

```
ssh -Y server1
```

On server1 I add an alias in .bashrc file:

```
alias gousr='cd /opt/user/myuser'
```

When I try to run `gousr` command at server1 xterm, it says "command not found". What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me. Have you run `source ~/.bashrc` since you last logged in/rebooted?

Comment: When I do `source ~/.bashrc` it says: `if: Expression Syntax` and the alias still does not work.

Comment: can you post the part of your `~/.bashrc` file that has an if statement?